# Variable returning answer and null

Tags: java, variables, printing, null, output

I recently created a program based off a video i saw. he program is supposed to convert 3 numbers into a time, checking them in the process. My problem is when i use System.out.print(variable name); it prints the variable and then on the next line it print null. I have deleted the System.out.println(variable name); and the null went away, so did the time. Im guessing its because i swaped the variable inbetween methods and classes, and i messed up somewhere.

Class Time_display

```
package Projects;

import java.util.*;
public class Time_display {
static int h=11;
static int m=56;
static int s=32;
static String temp;
public static void main(String[] args){

    Time object=new Time();
    object.Check(h,m,s);
    //object.mil(String temp);
    //String temp=object.mil(temp);
    Display(temp);


}public static void Display(String temp){
    System.out.println(temp);

}
}

CLass Time



package Projects;

public class Time {
private int hour=0;
private int minute=0;
private int second=0;
public String temp;
public void Check(int h, int m,int s){

    int hour=(h<24 && h>0 ? h:0);
    int minute=(m<60 && m>0 ? m:0);
    int second=(s<60 && s>0 ? s:0);

    //System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second);
    temp=String.format ("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    //System.out.println(temp);
    mil(temp);

}public String mil(String temp){

    Time_display object2=new Time_display();

    object2.Display(temp);

    return String.format ("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `main` method, you are outputting the class variable `temp`, but you have not assigned it anything...this is the source of your `null`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Time object=new Time();
    object.Check(h,m,s);
    //object.mil(String temp);
    //String temp=object.mil(temp);
    Display(temp);
}
```

The reason you are seeing it and the result is because in the `mil` method of your `Time` class, you are calling the `Display` method in your `Time_display` method...again...

```
public String mil(String temp){
    Time_display object2=new Time_display();
    // This value is not null...
    object2.Display(temp);
    return String.format ("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
}
```

Honestly, I have absolutely no idea what it is your are trying to achieve, but if I was doing this, I might be tempted to do something more like...

```
public class TimeDisplay {

    static int h = 11;
    static int m = 56;
    static int s = 32;
    static String temp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        display(Time.format(h, m, s));

    }

    public static void display(String temp) {
        System.out.println(temp);

    }

    public static class Time {

        public static String format(int h, int m, int s) {
            int hour = (h < 24 && h > 0 ? h : 0);
            int minute = (m < 60 && m > 0 ? m : 0);
            int second = (s < 60 && s > 0 ? s : 0);

            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
        }

    }

}
```

I would, also, highly recommend that you take the time to read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)